# Google Fonts API Not Working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to add Google API fonts to my webpage to learn more about HTML and I can't get any of the API fonts to load. I've been trying with the Santina font, but it always reverts back to my "default" Courier New font. The code worked when I added an @import statement to the top of the CSS document, so I believe the link is correct, but the HTML doc doesn't seem to link the API font to the CSS page. Am I overriding the CSS doc somehow?

My HTML doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generic Website Name</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita:400"
        ref="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:hsl(189,58%,71%);">
    <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
    <hr>
    <h3 class="headermain">Salutations!</h3>
    <p class="paramain">Welcome to the Website</p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS Doc:

```
#title {
    font-family:"Sansita", Courier New;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

 .headermain {
    color: #020202;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.paramain {
    color: #010101;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

Edit: added better spacing for code

Comment: Your code appears to correctly be loading the font. Have you tried clearing your cache with `CTRL` + `F5`, and also clearing your CSS cache by holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I've tried both and neither have changed the font on my screen. I'm using the most recent stable version of Firefox and Chrome to open the file via from a locally stored HTML file, not from a webserver. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: Both the `@import` and HTML `<link>` methods for Google Fonts should work; it seems odd that the latter wouldn't work for you. Using your above code exactly as it stands shows the font come through correctly for me. If it's not a caching issue, I can only assume that there's another rule with higher specificity that is overriding that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got ref="stylesheet" instead of rel="stylesheet"

Doh.

```css
#title {
    font-family:'Sansita', times, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

 .headermain {
    color: #020202;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.paramain {
    color: #010101;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generic Website Name</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita:400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:hsl(189,58%,71%);">
    <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
    <hr>
    <h3 class="headermain">Salutations!</h3>
    <p class="paramain">Welcome to the Website</p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google!</a>
</body>
</html>
```